# data not saving in database with fileupload in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

File uploading to uploads folder but not saving in the database, getting below error

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException Calling unknown
>   method: app\models\UploadForm::save()

Below is my controller code

```
$name =  $model->file->baseName . '.' .$model->file->extension;

$file = new UploadForm();
$file->image_name = $name;
$file->image_path = $name;
$file->save();
```

This is my model code

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

  public function rules()
    {
        //echo "in";
        return [
           [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
           ['image_path','string'],
        ];
    }
```

Can anyone help me? I am new to yii2

Comment: The error means that your `UploadForm` doesn't have `save()` method but you are trying to call it. It's probably because the `UploadForm` extends `yii\base\Model` that doesn't have the `save()` method. You should explain more about what you are trying to do and maybe show a little bit more of your code.

Comment: how to use this save method in namespace inside my code in yii2

Comment: as @MichalHynčica  said your UploadForm Model does extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord?

Comment: Tq u for your reply, actually i did not created model for table, i just created only model for form, that was the problem

Comment: $file->saveAs($destinationfilePath); and pass $destinationfilePath where you want to save it in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below code ?

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('Image Input Field Name');
if (!empty($file) && $file->extension != '') {
    $newFileName = rand() . '.' . $file->extension; 
    if ($file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $newFileName)) {
    
        // another code
    }
}
```